# Practical example of some AtomicInteger's methods

Tags: java, integer, atomic, atomicinteger

Could you please help me to grasp the gist of some methods of AtomicInteger class: `updateAndGet`, `accumulateAndGet`.

Why the first one recieves `IntUnaryOperator` as a parameter? What logic can potentially be applied in functional method of this interface? My thoughts, it would be easier to recieve just plain `int` value.  (Same with `IntBinaryOperator` interface).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

If you wanted to atomically double the value stored in an `AtomicInteger`, the best you could do before Java 8 was write

```
while (true) {
  int x = ai.get();
  if (ai.compareAndSet(x, 2 * x)) {
    return 2 * x;
  }
}
```

...but Java 8 lets you write e.g.

```
ai.updateAndGet(x -> 2 * x);
```

...and `accumulateAndGet` would, say, let you atomically multiply `ai` by `y` with

```
ai.accumulateAndGet(y, (x, y) -> x * y);
```

...which can also be implemented with `updateAndGet` but may be simpler to use in some cases where you already have a two-argument operation.